# how to prevent repeating request harming my server

Tags: node.js, express, ddos, rate-limiting

I have an nodejs express app,

I am okay with many request e.g. 1000 request to a api endpoint by 100 different people per hour,

but i want to prevent like 100 request on an api endpoint by a single ip or device, usually how to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: use express limiter https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx as a proxy to your nodejs app and then configure nginx to rate limit your requests

Refer :

https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/